# In Google Tag Manager, what is the difference between Click Target vs Click URL?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In the click triggers in Google Tag Manager what is the difference between Click Target vs Click URL?

Source: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106961?hl=en

Answer (score 7):

> Click Target: The target attribute of the clicked element.
>   Click URL: The HREF attribute of the clicked element, if any.

Per the link provided.

For a click URL it's associated with the HREF attribute of the clicked element or the link's destination. For the click target, its associated with the target attribute of the clicked element or specifies where to open the linked document. Which can be broken down to one of the following:

- _blank
- _parent
- _self
- _top
- framename

Details for each attribute can be found here - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

For Instance, let's take the HTML  tag with the following syntax:

```
<a href="http://example.com/going-here" target="_blank">Click Me</a>
```

For the tag manager the "Click URL" would be `http://example.com/going-here` and the "Click Target" would be `_blank`. So let's say you have a condition setup to match all "Click URL" going to `http://example.com` and also open in a new tab in your browser, then this `<a>` tag would satisfy your condition.